# Variable initialization from things included via use/only

Tags: initialization, fortran, scope, fortran90

I would like to create a variable in a module from quantities I've imported from another one. All the functions in this module will use the new variable, so I would prefer not to have to declare and assign it anew in every function. I'd like to declare and assign it once at the start and have it global to the entire module. But this does not work:

```
module example_mod
   use some_constants, only:derp, blah

   implicit none

   real, private :: derived_const = derp*(blah-1.0)/50.0   !doesn't work!

contains

!a whole bunch of functions that use derived_const
```

How can I get what I want?

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? Do you give `derp` and `blah` values when you declare them?

Comment: @Yossarian- the error I get is "Parameter 'derp' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression", and yes, everything in the `some_constants` module is assigned a value on declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that "derp" should be a constant.  You can make it one by adding to its declaration the specifier `parameter`.  This is also safer for constant variables because it will prevent the programmer from accidentally changing them.

Comment: Instead, is it possible to declare the variables and assign a value to it later, but outside any of the functions in the module? The module with the constants in it is not mine, so I can't edit it.

Comment: You can declare `derived_const` as you do now and just assign its value in a subroutine. Assuming you call this subroutine first, all the procedures in your module will still be able to use it. You won't be able to use it in any declaration lines, however.